# XPath how to get child nodes text and self

Tags: xml, xpath, web-scraping

I want an XPath to get all the text contained in a specific node and sub node.

In the example below I am trying to get: "Neil Carmichael (Stroud) (Con):"

```
<p>
<a class="anchor" name="qn_o0"> </a>
<a class="anchor" name="160210-0001.htm_wqn0"> </a>
<a class="anchor" name="160210109000034"> </a>
1. <a class="anchor" name="160210109000555"> </a>
    <b><b>Neil Carmichael</b>
     "(Stroud) (Con):"
    </b>
    "What assessment he has made of the value to the economy in Scotland of UK membership of the single market. [903484]"
</p>
```

So far I have managed to get only one part or the other using the following code:

```
from lxml import html 
import requests 
page = requests.get('http://www.publications.parliament.uk/pa/cm201516/cmhansrd/cm160210/debtext/160210-0001.htm') 
tree = html.fromstring(page.content) 

test2 = tree.xpath('//div[@id="content-small"]/p[(a[@name[starts-with(.,"st_o")]] or a[@name[starts-with(.,"qn_")]])]/b/text()')
```

Any help welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop your XPath at `/b` so it returns `<b>` elements instead of the text nodes inside `<b>`. Then you can call `text_content()` on each element to get the expected text output, for example :

```
from lxml import html

raw = '''<p>
<a class="anchor" name="qn_o0"> </a>
<a class="anchor" name="160210-0001.htm_wqn0"> </a>
<a class="anchor" name="160210109000034"> </a>
1. <a class="anchor" name="160210109000555"> </a>
    <b><b>Neil Carmichael</b>
     "(Stroud) (Con):"
    </b>
    "What assessment he has made of the value to the economy in Scotland of UK membership of the single market. [903484]"
</p>'''

root = html.fromstring(raw)
result = root.xpath('//p/b')
print result[0].text_content()

# output :
# 'Neil Carmichael\n     "(Stroud) (Con):"\n    '
```

As an alternative to `text_content()`, you can use XPath `string()` function and optionally `normalize-space()` :

```
print result[0].xpath('string(normalize-space())')
# output :
# Neil Carmichael "(Stroud) (Con):"
```

Comment: Thanks I tried something similar but the trick was to access one element at the time with [0].